# What's wrong with this Linear Algebra proof? Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

The question and proof is as follows:
http://i41.tinypic.com/5ahvuc.jpg

I get it up until the part where $u-\beta y \in W$. If this is true, then isn't $U=W$?
Furthermore, how could a single vector, $Ty$, span a vector space $V$, unless $Ty$ has only one element?

Comment: If $u-\beta y\in W$ for every $\beta$ or even for a fixed $\beta$ (across all $u\in U$), then you would have a point. However, $\beta$ depends on $u$, so we cannot make the jump to $U=W$.

Comment: To say a vector *spans* a vector space isn't to say it *equals* the vector space, only that the vector space consists of multiples of the one vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U=W$ means that the map $T$ sends every vector $u$ of $U$ in the zero-vector of $V$, meaning that $T$ is constant, always equal to $0$, but this is not the general case. To say that $U=W$ you should have that for every $u\in U$, it is $u\in W$, but you don't have this, you have that for every $u\in U$, $u-\beta y\in W$.

Moreover, there is nothing strange in a single vector family spanning a vector space, this means by definiton that every vector in the vector space can be expressed as a suitable scalar multiple of that unique vector. Do not confuse a set of vectors $S$ with the subspace $\langle S\rangle$ of vectors spanned by $S$.

Comment: The only thing I can't figure out is how $u-\beta y \in W$. It seems to have come from nowhere.

Comment: @user2116192 by definiton of $W$, a vector $v$ lies in $W$ iff $T$ sends $v$ to $0$, hence $u-\beta y$ lies in $W$ iff $T$ sends $u-\beta y$ to $0$, which is exactly what is written immediately before

Comment: It makes sense now (thanks!).